# git flow detached from release/v1.8

Tags: git, git-flow

I am getting into git flow on a project and trying to learn.

I had three features. I ran git flow feature finish on all three. Two gave me the commit message and one did not. All feature branches were merged into develop.

I pushed to the repo and pulled to staging.

When I checked out the release branch I got this message.

```
You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at 69ca088... Merge branch 'feature/12485--change-views-fontcolor' into develop
394elmp02:docroot 394e ((69ca088...)) $ git branch
* (detached from origin/release/v1.8)
  develop
  feature/12437--Update-Media-Disease-lp
  master
394elmp02:docroot 394e ((69ca088...)) $
```

the feature shown above is the one that didn't pop up a commit message.

I have no idea how to progress. Can someone share some insight.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured it out. There was a conflict with a feature branch that was on the staging site. Once I deleted that then re-checked out the release branch everything was all well.